# WCF Service Still Callable When Windows Service Has Been Stopped

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I have written a windows service in C# .NET. This windows service contains a WCF service. I then use a new ServiceHost in the OnStart of the windows service to listen for messages for the WCF service. And close this ServiceHost in the OnStop.

When the service is running I can call the WCF service just fine. However, I then stop the service but can still call the WCF service. I wasn't expecting this to happen. What is going on?

OnStart and OnStop code is below

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }

        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

        // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
        // listening for messages.
        serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please give us some code samples of onstop/onstart.

Comment: Can't be. It doesn't matter what you write in your code. If you have closed the windows service no WCF service is listening. I suggest you recheck your test.

Comment: I would like to know if OnStop is even being called, bc i agree with @Gilad

Comment: I've checked the services.msc and my service is stopped. I can definitely still call my WCF service though. My WCF service copies a file to an FTP server. I can see that a new file has been uploaded even though my windows service has been stopped.

Comment: Do you have a duplicate copy of your WCF service being hosted elsewhere, such as in Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't think so. How can I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this and thought I would update with the answer. Although I doubt anyone else would be so stupid ;)

I had added the reference to my client app by right clicking on the project and selecting "Add Reference" rather than "Add Service Reference". I am still not sure why this allows the service to be called when it is not running but now I have added it as a Service Reference everything works as expected.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: :) Presumably you were directly instantiating the service object in your client code, rather than a proxy? I once spent half a day looking for a bug in my client code when the debugger was breaking on an exception in the *service*, plain as day...

Answer (score 0):

Does your [OnStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop.aspx) method look something like this:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
  if (serviceHost != null)
  {
      try {
          serviceHost.Close();
      }catch{
          //could throw an exception if it is in a bad state
      }finally{
          serviceHost = null;
      }
  }
}
```

Second thing to check is that your OnStop is being called, it will not call stop if [`CanStop` flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canstop.aspx) is false.

Comment: without the try/catch/finally block (which I'll add) yes. I've put the code in the question.

Comment: I am guessing since you did not have the catch, there are no errors being logged when you stop it ?

Comment: no errors but I'll add the exception handling and see what happens.